# Is there any advantages to Windows To Go?

Tags: windows

Since people have been placing Windows on USB drives for live booting since Windows XP.

What makes Windows To Go worth the cost of an Enterprise License when you can use any version of Windows for a Live USB Stick?

Comment: Its non-trivial to create a bootable installation of Windows on a USB stick.  With Windows To Go it is trivial.

Comment: There is also the legal side to take under consideration. If MS sell Windows To Go, there MUST be a clause in the license of any other windows version against installing on a removable drive

Answer (score 0):

You can bring a Live Operating System along with all the programs and files along in a small USB Drive. And that you can take it anywhere and use on any PC? It is slower if you use a USB 2.0 port. But if you use a USB 3.0 port, you should be fine. And if you use an external hard drive, then you shouldn't notice any difference.
And Hint: You don't have to pay for a Enterprise Version! Search up "windows to go without enterprise"! Hope that helped!